# Service fabric auto scaling micro services without using -1

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How do I use auto scale stateless services with out  -1. what I want to achieve is if a micro service  is set to 3 instances for 5 instances available. now if I increase to the instance to 10 then the micro service should auto scale to 6. -1 does not help here as it occupies all the instances in a node when number of instances increases.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the instance count to -1, you are telling that the number of instances is dynamic based on the number of available nodes, you should not use it for auto scaling unless you really want to tie the number of instances to the number of available nodes.

This other question should give more insights:
[Service Fabric set instance count -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112839/service-fabric-set-instance-count-1/50114654#50114654)

Your options are either: set the instance count manually or use auto scaling like described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-autoscaling)

In any of the cases, the number of instances are limited to the number of nodes, these issues were explained in this answer: 
[Does service fabric create singleton instance for each stateful partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927776/does-service-fabric-create-singleton-instance-for-each-stateful-partition/50929864#50929864)